# Some elements are disappears in PHPBB3

Tags: css, phpbb3

I have a new installation of PHPBB3.
And I have a problem, that some elements are disappear.
Such as: "edit post", "delete post" (on a viewtopic.php pages).
In CSS (for "Edit post" - span element) a see:

```
media="screen, projection"
ul.profile-icons li span {
display: none;
}
```

I use a default 'prosilver' theme.
What is the reason of this problem and how to fix it?
(I am very new to PHPBB)

Comment: User might not have previledge for it..

Comment: I am an admin... Also "private message" link is disappear to.

Comment: Is the link still present in the HTML and just hidden with the CSS rule you gave ?

Comment: Yes the links are present in HTML. And I use a default theme ("prosilver").

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Have you made any modifications? Have you adjusted any permissions? Are they gone in all browsers or just certain ones?